# How do I get rid of speaker static?

Tags: amplifier, audio, static

I made the basic [TPA1517](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa1517.pdf) circuit as shown on page 11 of the datasheet. When there is nothing plugged into the input, there is a lot of static. When I do plug something in, there is less static, but it is still noticeable and is still there when I play music. What kind of circuit would I have to add to this to get rid of that static?

It is a constant and regular hum, so I know its not radio interference in the wires. All the grounds are connected together, so I don't think its anything to do with that.

Comment: What frequency is the hum? If the circuit is mains powered, what happens if you short the inputs and pull the power plug out? Do you have any shielding around the device? Please show us your circuit diagram (including power supply) and physical construction.

Comment: Hum isn't 'static' and it doesn't originate with the speakers. It is coming from the amplifier.

Comment: Static is a common American term to describe white noise.  Like if you tune an analog tv to the wrong channel it will just be white-black pixels and a shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting interference from the AC->DC power supply.  This can happen if you have a poorly regulated power supply, so that some magnitude of the AC wall voltage (~120V) is coupled onto the DC output voltage (between 5V and 12V, probably).  This in turn gets transmitted through the circuit and shows up at the output as a hum at the AC wall frequency (60Hz) or its harmonics (120Hz, 180Hz, 240Hz...etc).

[mains-hum-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum)

You could try powering from a battery; if this fixes the problem you know for sure that you need to improve the power supply.  Alternatively, listen to the sounds in the wiki link.  If it sounds similar, it's probably due to AC interference.

In this case, you could use a band-stop filter.  However, I consider this the tail wagging the dog and it would be a lot easier and provide better quality audio if you just fix the power supply or replace it.

Comment: That does sound the same as the 60Hz. I am going to power this in the end with a Li-ion battery, which is shipping right now. Its the only battery that will be able to power this considering that it is a 12V system. I will try that out and hopefully it will work!

Comment: Awesome.  Laptop chargers are pretty well regulated and I have used them in the past to power 12-18V guitar pedals.